# How did this affect Thanos and Hulk differently?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-endgame, thanos

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Hulk wore all the Infinity Stones he was instantly getting major injury before he even snapped just by putting on the gauntlet. Whereas Thanos in *Avengers: Infinity War* was able to wield and use all 6 (not all of them at once) without injury (until he snapped). Is this because the nano gauntlet and the IW gauntlet are different?

Comment: Tony didn't care about the safety of the wielder, whereas Dwarves did.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 That seems so far fetched I highly doubt it is true. And in fact Tony is _more likely_ to care for the safety of whoever wears it than Eitri is for Thanos.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Only if he could fully reverse engineer the original Gauntlet. It's not easy to build perfect product. People often overlook things.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 So you're saying Tony didn't care for the safety of the wielder because he couldn't build a perfect product and overlooked things? You seem to be adding 2 and 2 together to make 5.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Seat belts are designed to protect passengers during car crash. But, the same belt can trap you inside water. A perfect car should automatically retract belts if car starts to submerge in water (an alien car possibly). An engineer who cares more on safely than functionality would give alien car's every feature attention.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 I don't even know how to reply to that, that's just.... yeah.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 I think it's more likely that Tony and Bruce are simply less capable than three hundred magic space dwarves and their ancient star forge.

Comment: Thanos != Hulk, Thanos did defeat Hulk pretty easily in Infinity War

Answer (score 11):

## Because Thanos is stronger than the Hulk.

The screenwriters Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely have said in previous interviews that Thanos is simply stronger than Hulk, that is why he could beat him so easily at the start of *Avengers: Infinity War*.

> I think he could. I may be speaking out of turn, but I think Thanos could kick the Hulk's ass without the (Power Stone).
>
> [...]
>
> We want to announce Thanos as the biggest villain in the MCU, so he takes out the previous reigning champion. And by defeating Hulk relatively easily and savagely, hopefully there's a sense of dread over the course of the rest of the movie for anyone else who comes up against him.
>
> <sub>[MovieWeb, Infinity War Writers Say Thanos Could've Beaten Hulk, Power Stone or Not](https://movieweb.com/infinity-war-writers-thanos-beat-hulk/)</sub>

On top of this Hulk is struggling a lot longer with the Gauntlet on because he is fighting the Infinity Stones to try and bring Nat back but it wouldn't let him. I.e. his snap was more than just a quick "kill 50% of all life" but a back and forth fight.

> **Bruce:** You know, I tried. When I had the gauntlet, the stones, I really tried to bring her back.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

His snap attempt is instant, as in he puts the Gauntlet on and instantly starts trying to bring Nat back and do the snap. Had he left it on for a bit before attempting the snap the effects probably would have died down as we see when Thanos wears it.

Of course the two Gauntlets are different as well, made of different materials and designs. One would speculate that whilst the Infinity Gauntlet is probably made of a stronger material (Uru most likely but it's never mentioned), the Stark Gauntlet is an improved-upon design. Note that Tony, Professor Hulk and Rocket oversee its creation and they all incredibly clever. They've all also come into contact with The Infinity Stones before, and Tony and Banner also made extended analysis of the Mind Stone.

They also probably have the Infinity Gauntlet to look at after Thanos' death so can reverse engineer that. It's likely that the Stark Gauntlet could even be a better version than the original.

Comment: Your last inference is wrong. Bruce tried to bring her back at the time of the snap.

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 Which is what my point is. Edited to clarify a bit though.

Comment: But, the question asks about the duration before the snap.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Different Gauntlet composition

The gauntlet in Infinity War (**Thanos-Gauntlet**) was forged by Eitri, the Dwarf King using

> **Uru** (the metal used to make Mjolnir).

The material used to make the **Iron-Gauntlet** on the other hand isn’t specified but it’s speculated to be made using

> **Vibranium**, *the strongest metal on Earth*

---

### 2. Hulk vs. Thanos

As seen during the fight between the two in the beginning of **Infinity War**, and as mentioned by MovieHub [here](https://movieweb.com/infinity-war-writers-thanos-beat-hulk/), Thanos is way more powerful (both mentally and physically) than The Hulk.

Answer (score -6):

Thanos is often stated to be the most powerful being in the universe before getting the stones. Hulk is just a gamma victim.

Comment: If you could [edit] in one of the relevant quotes this would greatly improve the answer.